# How to show the data obtained from server in the table view cells when data is entered into searchbar and search button is clicked

Tags: tableview, nsurlsession, searchbar

I am new to ios development and working on services first time..When the user types something in the searchbar and clicks search button of keyboard it obtains response from server.The response from server is as follows:

```
 (
        {
        Id = 2;
        Name = Alex;
    },
        {
        Id = 5;
        Name = AMark;
    }
)
```

I want to show this name obtained from server on click of search button of keyboard on the label of table view cells.How can I do this.Kindly suggest.

Comment: Some more information would be helpful: What version of iOS are you targeting? Are you using Swift or Objective-C? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for: [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller)?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it..it was because of wrong constraints.